# Integrating Authorize.net and codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, e-commerce, authorize.net

Hello I have a web application and I would like to start integrating charging debit/credit cards online and I am confused as to why my code is not working. I am new to online payments and the documention to start is very unclear. I am using Codeigniter 3. Here is some sample code from what I am using

/* Included at the top of the file*/

```
use assets\libraries\authorize\lib\net\authorize\api\contract\v1 as AnetAPI;
use assets\libraries\authorize\lib\net\authorize\api\controller as AnetController;
```

/* Model Function */

```
      // Common setup for API credentials
  $merchantAuthentication = new AnetAPI\MerchantAuthenticationType();
  $merchantAuthentication->setName(""); //ID
  $merchantAuthentication->setTransactionKey(""); //Key
  $refId = 'ref' . time();
  // Create the payment data for a credit card
  $creditCard = new AnetAPI\CreditCardType();
  $creditCard->setCardNumber("card was here"); //This had actual value
  $creditCard->setExpirationDate("expire was here");//This had actual value
  $creditCard->setCardCode("code was here"); //This had actual value
  $paymentOne = new AnetAPI\PaymentType();
  $paymentOne->setCreditCard($creditCard);
  $order = new AnetAPI\OrderType();
  $order->setDescription("desceiption was here"); //This had actual value
  //create a transaction
  $transactionRequestType = new AnetAPI\TransactionRequestType();
  $transactionRequestType->setTransactionType( "authCaptureTransaction"); 
  $transactionRequestType->setAmount(1.00);
  $transactionRequestType->setOrder($order);
  $transactionRequestType->setPayment($paymentOne);

  $request = new AnetAPI\CreateTransactionRequest();
  $request->setMerchantAuthentication($merchantAuthentication);
  $request->setRefId( $refId);
  $request->setTransactionRequest( $transactionRequestType);
  $controller = new AnetController\CreateTransactionController($request);
  $response = $controller->executeWithApiResponse( \net\authorize\api\constants\ANetEnvironment::PRODUCTION);

  if ($response != null)
  {
    $tresponse = $response->getTransactionResponse();
    if (($tresponse != null) && ($tresponse->getResponseCode()== \SampleCode\Constants::RESPONSE_OK) )   
    {
      echo "Charge Credit Card AUTH CODE : " . $tresponse->getAuthCode() . "\n";
      echo "Charge Credit Card TRANS ID  : " . $tresponse->getTransId() . "\n";
    }
    else
    {
        echo  "Charge Credit Card ERROR :  Invalid response\n";
    }

  }
  else
  {
    echo  "Charge Credit card Null response returned";
  }
```

No error is being returned from the script but no money is being charged and I am confused why. If anyone could tell me the correct way to get started and how to accept a payment online It would be VERY appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure you are not in test mode or using the testing sandbox?

Comment: I have the ANetEnviroment set to production and I had the proper keys. Is there something I am missing?

Comment: Make sure you are not in test mode

Comment: @JohnConde my mode on the authorize.net account is set to live. I double checked.

Comment: The only other place they could be is in your unsettled transactions

Comment: @JohnConde I looked in there and It doesn't look like the charges are even hitting the account. But no error code shows up on my script?

Comment: 1) If you are just starting out then you should only be using the sandbox not live. 2) You are trying to immediately implement a complicated script but you don't even know if you are calling it correctly yet. You might need to put it in the codeigniter library and call it that way. So take like the first 3 lines of your script and wrap it an IF and see if that works. 3) Then work through the rest one chunk at a time confirming its working as you go.